# problemas con el metodo destructor

Tags: c++

Estoy haciendo practica de POO y tengo un problema. Cuando agrego un objeto al vector, este se me destruye cuando termino la operación.
Este es el método que me da problemas:

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
class Estudiante {
    ...
    public:
        ...
        virtual ~Estudiante();
};
```

```
#include "estudiante.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
Estudiante::Estudiante() {
    nombre = " ";
    edad = 0;
}
...
Estudiante::~Estudiante() { std::cout << "Objeto eliminado."<<std::endl; }
```

Y este el operador:

```
#include "controlador.h"
...
#include "estudiante.h"
#include <vector> 
void Controller::control() {
   std::vector<Estudiante> vec;
   UI ui;
   int choice = 0;
   while (true) {
       ui.write("Menu:");
       ui.write("1. Crear estudiante.");
       ui.write("2. Lista.");
       ...
       ui.write("8. Salir");
       choice = ui.readInt("Digite el numero a escoger:");
       std::string nombre;
       int edad = 0;
       Estudiante est;
       int num;
       switch (choice){
           case 1:
               vec.push_back(est);
               nombre = ui.readString("Digite el nombre del estudiante:");
               est.setNombre(nombre);
               edad = ui.readInt("Digite la edad del estudiante:");
               est.setEdad(edad);
               break;
           case 2:
               for (Estudiante& e : vec)
                   ui.write(e.toString());
               break;
           ...
           case 8:
               return;
           default:
               ui.write("Digite un valor valido.");
               break;
       }
   }
}
```

El problema en especifico es que al agregar un objeto al vector de estudiantes, este se elimina cuando termina las operaciones del caso y vuelve al menú. Cuando hago el comando lista me aparece el numero de objetos que agregué, pero son los objetos default, y estos también se eliminan al terminar.
Sospecho que este problema podria arreglarse si convierto las operaciones del switch en metodos, pero no me siento seguro con esa solucion.

Answer (score 1):

Si consultamos la documentación de la función [`vector::push_back`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) nos indica que hace una copia del objeto proveído:

> #### std::vector<T,Allocator>::push_back
>
> `constexpr void push_back( const T& value );` (1)
>
> `constexpr void push_back( T&& value );` (2)
>
> Appends the given element value to the end of the container.
>
> 1. **The new element is initialized as a copy of value**.
> 2. value is moved into the new element.

Si quieres evitar destrucciones "*de más"*, no puedes usar `vector::push_back`, porque tanto si lo copias como si lo mueves acabas llamando al destructor del elemento original que se ha copiado o movido.

Para evitar destrucciones "*de más*", debes construir el objeto directamente dentro del vector usando [`vector::emplace_back`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back):

```
       // Estudiante est; // No crear objeto temporal
       int num;
       switch (choice){
           case 1:
           {
               // Emplace devuelve una referencia al elemento insertado
               auto est = vec.emplace_back();
               nombre = ui.readString("Digite el nombre del estudiante:");
               est.setNombre(nombre);
               edad = ui.readInt("Digite la edad del estudiante:");
               est.setEdad(edad);
           }
           break;
```

Answer (score 0):

[`push_back`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) crea una copia del parámetro al final del vector, no guarda una referencia.

Lo que sucede es que llamas a `push_back` antes de modificar `nombre` y `edad` entonces esa información se pierde, pero verás que los `Estudiante`s están ahí si imprimes `vec.size()`.

Y lo que se crea y se destruye una y otra vez es la variable local `Estudiante est`.

Las veces que se copia el `Estudiante` no aparecen porque se llama al constructor de copia por defecto. Si deseas verlo, la declaración es la siguiente:

```
Estudiante(const Estudiante& otro){
    ...
}
```